# Copy current directory in to docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When building my Docker image I need to copy all of the files in the same directory in to the Docker image.

I attempted to do this

```
ADD ./* $HOME/src

RUN ls $HOME/src
```

but it doesn't seem to work

```
ls: cannot access /root/src: No such file or directory
```

How would I go about copying all of the current directory and subdirectories in to my docker image while building?

Comment: share your docker file. did you define $HOME . the issue with not the host the issue with docker image . If you using alpine there no src in the root try to create src in root first

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was building the images using `docker build - < Dockerfile` which apparently doen't send the build context so things can't be copied. After changing to `docker build .` and adding the / like MB11 suggested the build worked.

Comment: I am doing the same, and is there a way to add context with `docker build - < Dockerfile`?

Comment: Figure it out,  use `docker build -f Dockerfile .`

Comment: True, i just encountered the same situation and your solution resolves

Answer (score 28):

Just add / at the end of src in ADD statement.

```
ADD ./* $HOME/src/
```

Comment: Just a minor remark - using `./*` seems to copy all files as a flat list into src (I used `COPY` instead of `ADD` but I doubt there lies the difference). If you want to copy the current project as is, better use `COPY . /src/`

Comment: OP, please modify your answer based on @ShovalSadde's suggestion. `COPY . /dest/directory` is indeed the right way to do it. Especially to maintain directory structure, etc.