# COPY files in current local directory only and do not include subdirectories in Docker?

Tags: docker

Given a Git repository as Docker context:

```
my_project_dir
├── Dockerfile 
├── run_myapp.py
├── requirements.txt 
├── dir1
│   └── ... some files
└── dir2
    └── ... some files
```

I want to use `COPY` to move the `run_myapp.py` and `requirements.txt` but not the two directories.  I want to keep my Docker image light so I don't want to include the directories; those are used for other services.

Currently I have `COPY` used as follows:

```
...

COPY run_myapp.py run_myapp.py
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt 
...
```

I don't want to use `COPY . .` since this will copy everything.

I there a way to specify all docs but not directories?

### What I've tried

I read [Copy current directory in to docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49683612/8278075) and some similar questions outside of StackOverflow like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/docker-copy-instruction/ but none answer my question.

Comment: 1. You can  copy multiple files in a single command `COPY run_myapp.py requirements.txt /targetdirectory/`. 2. you could simply put all undesired files and directories into a `.dockerignore` file. Those files will then be skipped when you use `COPY . .`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dockerfile `COPY` syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) supports shell globs but doesn't support any sort of matching on file type.  You can copy all things with a given *name* `*.py` but not "only files".  For the actual glob syntax it delegates to the [Go `path/filepath` module](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match) which supports only the basic `*`, `?`, and `[a-z]` characters as "special".

You aren't limited to a single file in a `COPY` command, though, as @JoachimSauer notes in a comment, and you don't have to spell out the destination directory or filename on the right-hand side.  A relative path like `.` is relative to the current `WORKDIR`.  So here I might write

```sh
WORKDIR /app
COPY run_myapp.py requirements.txt .
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.dockerignore` file with the following content should do the trick:

```
*/*
```